# Get Queryset values for form MultipleChoice in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to display more then one value from the Queryset inside my form, but can't get the values out.

i have tried to use `forms.locations.all` and loop through them.
`forms.locations.1` looked like it would work, but
`forms.locations.1.name forms.locations.1.street` didn't work either.

Is there a way to display more then just the name of the queryset inside the form?

I'm aware that this is a Field. I'm trying to replicate something in the Admin Dashboard functionality.
I have an unknown number of multiple choices. And need to be able to add these choices to a many to many field. This is already working, but only the name of the queryset items is displayed in the form, which is a problem. Some have the same name and so on. I need to display something like the fields = ['name', 'street', 'street_number', 'postal_code', 'city'] inside the admin.

Anyone got any ideas?

forms.py

```
class GroupCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

locations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'styled', "style":"margin:10px;"}), queryset=None)      
group_name = forms.CharField(label='', required=True ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'rows': '1', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Geben Sie den Gruppen Namen an'}))

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(GroupCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['locations'].queryset = LocationData.objects.all().filter(email=user.email)

class Meta: 
    model = GroupManagement
    fields = ['group_name', 'locations']
```

views.py

```
  def page_groups(request, page_group):



form = GroupCreateForm(data=request.POST or None, user=request.user)



if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        group_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        group_name = form.cleaned_data['group_name']
        group_id = group_name.replace(' ', '')
        group_instance.group_id = group_id
        group_instance.email = request.user.email
        group_instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()





context = {

'form': form,

}

return render(request, 'dashboard/create_group.html', context)
```

views.py

```
 <div class="col-md-12">


            <div class="panel">

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="tab-content with-panel">

                        <div id="line-blue" class="tab-pane">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <div class="inputer">
                                        <div class="input-wrapper">
                                            {{form.group_name}}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-green btn-flat btn-ripple">Erstellen</button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12 locations">


                                        {{form.locations}}

                                </div>



                            </div><!--.row-->
                        </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    </div>



                    </div><!--.tab-content-->
                </div><!--.panel-body-->


        </div><!--.col-md-6-->
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `form.locations` is a field, not a queryset. Where are you trying to display a queryset?

Comment: I'm aware of that, i'm trying to replicate something the admin dashboard has. Check buttons with actual information and then add the information to a many to many field. Is there any way to do replicate the list the admin dashboard has? The delete function looks like it has some similiarities.

Comment: And i added a queryset here, self.fields['locations'].queryset = LocationData.objects.all().filter(email=user.email). So i thought i could access more information.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i added more information above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error here is the solution.

Of course it is possible to access a queryset through a Field and displaying a Multiple Choice like in the Admin.
Even though otherwise indicated.

You can't use more values inside a form tag. So the solution is to split the form into smaller parts. 
A multiple Choice form usually looks like this:

```
<li>
  <label for="id"><input class="styled" id="id" 
  name="formfield name" type="checkbox" value="1">
  queryset item name
 </label>
```

The value one is the primaryKey set by the Form. So in order for Django to still understand a many to many field you need the formfield name and the primary key.

So now the part i was stuck with how do i get these values ?

```
{% for item in form."querysetname".field.queryset.all %} 
<li>
  <input name="formfieldname" type="checkbox"value="{{item.pk}}"> 
    {{item.querysetitem}} {{item.querysetitem}} {{item.querysetitem}} 

</li>

 {% endfor %}
```

The item.pk stands for the primary key. 
The formfield name can just be copied.

Hope that helps in case someone needs a many to many field, with a db queryset and a form.